# check resultset for emptiness in clojure jdbc

Tags: jdbc, clojure, compojure, cheshire

i'm using clojure with jdbc, compojure, cheshire, postgresql, c3p0, tryin make REST. When i'm using this code as handler

```
  (defn get-document [id]
      (sql/query (db-connection)
                 ["select * from document where id = cast(? as integer)" id]
                 {:row-fn
                  (fn [first]
                                   (if (empty? first )
                                     (response "empty")
                                     (response first)
                                     ))}))
```

If reslutset is not empty i have response as i need, but if its empty i got empty brackets [].

Also this is my project dependencies

```
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]
                 [compojure "1.5.1"]
                 [ring/ring-json "0.4.0"]
                 [c3p0/c3p0 "0.9.1.2"]
                 [ring/ring-defaults "0.2.1"]
                 [org.clojure/java.jdbc "0.7.3"]
                 [org.postgresql/postgresql "42.1.4"]
                 [cheshire "5.8.0"]]
```

Comment: `[]` is an empty vector. What did you expect to get (presumably `nil`)? Why is `[]` being returned a problem?

Comment: i'm tryna make custom response if vector is empty, and how i know predicate (empty?) must work with it, but its not, i don't understand what i'm doing wrong

Comment: I think I understand now. You are expecting to see the response "empty", but not getting it.

Comment: The other point to note is that if you do a (first rs) where rs is your result set and rs is empty, first will return nil, so (if (nil? (first rs)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:row-fn` function is executed for each row in the result set. When your result set is empty, row-fn is not called.

You may need to use the result of `sql/query` to handle the response of the query. When there is no result an empty vector is returned (this is `[]`). You can check if the result is empty by calling `empty?`. Something like this:

```
(defn get-document [id]
  (let [query ["select * from document where id = cast(? as integer)" id]
        rows  (sql/query (db-connection) query)]
      (if (empty? rows)
        (response "empty")
        (response (first rows)))))
```

Comment: You should wrap the sql call in a try/catch in case of connection or db errors. When your only interested in the first record, you can do a (first (sql/query....) (catch Excepton e (log .getMesage e) nil) so that you either get a record or get nil